Service is acting late when Integration tests with Jasmine and Angular
The component:
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public flag = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    console.log("HomePage Created");
    this.authService.subject.subscribe(res => {
      this.flag = res;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

The service:
export class AuthService {
  public subject = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    console.log("AuthService created");
    this.storage.create().then(() => {
      this.storage.set('token', true).then(() => {
        this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
          console.log("token sent");
          this.subject.next(token);
        })
      })
    });
  }
}

The tests:
describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component: HomePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage)
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', async () => {
    await fixture.whenStable()
    console.log("test run");
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

The test output:
24 05 2024 17:19:33.830:INFO [Chrome 115.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket ZveuSQt62spdgsS6AAAF with id 45284113
LOG: 'AuthService created'
Chrome 115.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'HomePage Created'
Chrome 115.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'test run'
Chrome 115.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 4 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'token sent'
Chrome 115.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 4 (skipped 3) SUCCESS (0.056 secs / 0.04 secs)
LOG: 'token sent'
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS

The problem:
As you can see, the token is sent AFTER the tests run. This is a very simplified case of another use case where the DOM components are not updating because of the token not being received by the component before the tests run. Is there a way I can make sure the service triggers the value before the assertions run? I don't want to mock the service, because I want to achieve integration test if possible.
I Tried multiple combinations of fixture.whenStable() and fixture.detectChanges() but no luck
